# How to Use F3 without Fn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to get the coordinates with the <kbd>F3</kbd> key on Minecraft Java Edition. I would like to know how to use the <kbd>F3</kbd> key without using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I have looked in the controls and haven't found anything, I've looked for other questions like this but have not found an answer.

Comment: I read the question as "how do I reconfigure my keyboard to make pressing Fn not necessary", which is off-topic as blatantly unrelated to gaming, and probably belongs on Super User, but is not a duplicate.

Comment: not really sorry

Comment: im just confused because one day it just refused to work and its really dumb and im mad

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting <kbd>Fn + Esc</kbd>, which should be your <kbd>FnLock</kbd> toggle. This works like Caps Lock, except it's for the function key instead of shift. This should mean that you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> without having to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>.